# Elasticsearch Sync with Hibernate Transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate, elasticsearch, compass-lucene

I have an application running on spring2.5, hibernate 3.1 and compass search engine.The compass search engine is synchronized with all db operations. So that I can get the data from compass cache quickly. Now I would like to replace compass with Elastic search engine .I'm newer to elastic search and I think the author of compass was developed the elastic search. So that the synchronization mechanism should implemented in elastic search also. Anyone please suggest a way how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know compass but Elasticsearch is search server on top of Lucene.
And the only thing it does is update the search index based on a database query.
This can be triggered manually or based on a timestamp filed in the database.

https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc

Comment: Thank you simas for your immediate reply. You mentioned is something different approach but I'm looking like for the configuration for ES as given here

Comment: <bean id="compass" class="org.compass.spring.LocalCompassBean">
  <property name="resourceLocations">
   <list>
    <value>classpath:admin.cmd.xml</value>
    <value>classpath:admin.cpm.xml</value>
   </list>
  </property>
  <property name="compassSettings">
   <props>
    <prop key="compass.engine.connection">file://${user.home}/compass/admin</prop>
    <prop key="compass.transaction.factory">org.compass.spring.transaction.SpringSyncTransactionFactory</prop>
   </props>
  </property>
  <property name="transactionManager">
   <ref local="transactionManager" />
  </property>
 </bean>

Comment: Here org.compass.spring.transaction.SpringSyncTrans‌​actionFactory is responsible for transaction sync

Answer (score 0):

[Hibernate Search](http://hibernate.org/search/) provides a similar integration as Compass Search used to do.

Older versions of Hibernate Search would only provide Lucene embedded, but [the latest is giving the option of using Elasticsearch instead](http://in.relation.to/2016/05/24/ElasticsearchintegrationReachesBeta1/).

This is in pretty good shape already, but highly contributed too so it's a great time to try it out and let us know what you feel is missing.

The catch is that it requires to use Hibernate ORM at version 5.0.0 at least: please upgrade Hibernate (you will benefit from that in many other ways too, not least much higher performance).